# Interchanging Two Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Does the convergence of the left hand side imply the convergence of the right hand side and the equality of the two sides? Do we need further requirement for the function $f(j,k)$?

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{k} f(j,k) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=j}^\infty f(j,k)$$

Answer (score 1):

Convergence of the left hand side does not imply convergence of the right hand side, as can be seen by the following example: 
$$ f(j,k) = \begin{cases} 1 & j = 0\\
                         -1 & 0 < j = k\\
                          0 & \text{otherwise}
            \end{cases}
$$ 
Then 
$$ \sum_{j=0}^k f(j,k) = \delta_{k0}, \text{ hence} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^k f(j,k) = 1$$
converges, but 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty f(0,k) = \infty $$
so the right hand side does not converge.

Of course, if either side converges absolutely, both sides converge, and we have equality.

Comment: I think you would say the **right** hand side does not converge! Am I right? :)

Comment: Right. Going to correct it, thx.

Comment: Indeed, but I think the big question refers to: if the partial sums converges, then such equality holds.